# UTF-8 decode from one text file to another

Tags: c#, utf-8

I have a text file (in real it is a *.cs file) which contains a strings like this

```
if (buffer.Substring(len - 2, len).Equals("\u00e1\u010d") || // -áč
    buffer.Substring(len - 2, len).Equals("a\u010d") || //-ač
    buffer.Substring(len - 2, len).Equals("\u00e1n") || //-án
    buffer.Substring(len - 2, len).Equals("\u00e1\u0159") || //-ář
```

I want tot copy the file to a new with changing the unicode sequences

```
\u00e1\u010d
```

to the symbols

```
-áč
```

so finally I want to get the file with the next strings

```
if (buffer.Substring(len - 2, len).Equals("áč") || // -áč
    buffer.Substring(len - 2, len).Equals("ač") || //-ač
    buffer.Substring(len - 2, len).Equals("án") || //-án
    buffer.Substring(len - 2, len).Equals("ář") || //-ář
```

can anybody help me with this problem, please?

Comment: What charset should the new file be. The codes you see are the Unicode chars, if you replace them with chars and save to unicode they will end up the same codes as far as I know, but if the target is ISO-8829-<x> then its another matter.

Comment: the final file will be UTF-8. The comments in the file are displayed normal in Visual Studio